# Black screen when accessing the UEFI firmware settings using a specific SSD

Tags: hard-drive, boot, ssd, uefi

I'm trying to access my UEFI firmware settings to change the main boot directory to GRUB on my SSD *(Windows is on the HDD)*, however whenever I try to launch the UEFI firmware settings, I'm met with a black screen.

- After removing the SSD, the UEFI firmware settings boots completely normal *(with certain small flaws caused by Windows)*
- Removing the HDD and booting with only the SSD shows a black screen when opening the UEFI firmware settings

  - Connecting a different SSD does work with/without the HDD, with the UEFI firmware settings booting normally

I've already tried updating the UEFI firmware, checking for HDD and SSD errors with AOMEI partition assistant and some Windows default commands, so it must be some error from either the SSD itself or the motherboard, but I doubt it's the motherboard since it works with other SSDs.

Asus ROG GL553VD

- Intel i5 7300HQ
- GTX 1050 mobile
- 32 GB DDR3 RAM
- SSD: HFM512GDJTNG-8310A

Comment: Is it an internal SSD (inside the case)? Does the SSD work when you boot from Windows? If the answer for the last question is No, have you tried the SSD in an enclosure or on another computer?

Comment: @harrymc yes, it is an internal SSD, and it did work when it had windows, now it has Linux, which also worked with no problem when I was able to boot into it.

Comment: When booting into Windows, does the SSD appear (if you can carefully hot-plug it in)? Is it possible that the SSD was somehow damaged?

Comment: @harrymc when booting into windows the SSD appears, and when booting into the UEFI too, as I tried to reset the UEFI by taking the cmos out and putting it back, and it worked but once I rebooted it wouldn't work anymore. Now, about hot-plugging it in, do you mean when the UEFI is open? I don't think it would work, I cannot even plug USB drives while the UEFI is open. But I don't see myself skilled enough to do something as risky as that.

Comment: I got the impression that you disconnect the cable for the SSD in order to boot into Windows, which is why I asked about re-connecting it (hot-plug) after the boot into Windows is finished.

Comment: I suggest you do some more troubleshooting as directed above, just in case. That said, the symptom points to an about to fail drive so keep that in mind and act accordingly. PS - *with certain small flaws caused by Windows* This is incorrect, very much so. No OS cause flaws to the firmware, it always boots BEFORE any OS. "Flaws"/bugs can exist in any code including firmware (UEFI, BIOS, other), reason why vendor release updates. It's probably advisable to do that in your case but, for reference, it has nothing to do with Windows or any other OS.

Comment: @ChanganAuto microsoft somehow forces some boot options into my UEFI which aren't the windows boot manager. This being zorin, which once installed and now removed, and Ubuntu, which I never installed. I know this was caused by windows because these were added automatically after re-imaging the drive and now they aren't deleteable. Also, what more kind of troubleshooting, I think I've tried everything, and how do I check whether my drive is going to fail or not? Crystal Disk Info says it's at 56% health, and the drive is relatively new, only 2-3 years old. My HDD is like 7 and is fine.

Comment: No, you don't understand UEFI mode (and it boots and requirements). Those boot stanzas are there because the bootloaders are still in the ESP (EFI System Partition). Deleting an OS *system* partition does NOT delete the .efi files in the ESP from where all OSes boot from. The firmware (UEFI) merely READS what's in the ESP and add it to its boot menu. Blaming this on Microsoft or Windows is simply hilarious, beyond believe. No installed OS has anything to do with this process whatsoever. This comment is about the hilarious misunderstanding only. Next I'll try to addres the actual issue here...

Comment: CrystalDisk is not a reliable tool to assess this (possible) problem. But 56% in a 2-3 years old drive is worrisome in itself, no doubt about it. With a very high degree of certainty the drive IS failing and preventing normal access to the firmware settings is probably just the beginning. **If you have valuable personal files there you should backup ASAP**. Drives, of any type, can fail at any time. I have SSDs from almost 10 years ago still working fine and I've had HDDs fail after a little more than 2 years.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Files are backed up. But is there any way to fix the UEFI black screen problem or I'll just have to get a new SSD?

Comment: Any defective or failing drive of any kind may prevent access to the firmware settings (UEFI or with old BIOS happened the same), be it HDD, SSD, optical, diskette, or any USB mass storage device and even other USB peripherals. So, yes, very likely you'll have to replace it an, honestly, I think you know that already. Your troubleshooting has been thorough, maybe missing the test of that same drive in a different known good desktop PC but even that would be to rule out some 'weird' problem stemming from the combination with a specific motherboard (again, unlike, because it partially works).